# How to validate if a password meets the length requirements only if it isn't empty?

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I'm making an ASP.NET MVC application in which a user needs to be able to change his/her password.

In the EditUser page, I need to validate the password matches a certain regex and has a given length, and I'm required to show a different message when the password is not long enough and when it includes forbiden characters.

Also, I must not change the password if the user leaves that field untouched.

The Password member in my ViewModel looks like this:

```
//[StringLength(40, ErrorMessage = "Password between 3 and 40 characters", MinimumLength = 3)]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[ValidatePasswordLengthAttribute]
[RegularExpression(@"^()|([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,40})$", ErrorMessage = "Error en el formato de la contraseña.")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

I've tried using two regex, in the hope that it will validate the first one and, if that is succesful, the second one, but you can't repeat that attribute:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^()|(.{3,40})$", ErrorMessage = "Password entre 3 y 40 caracteres")]
[RegularExpression(@"^()|([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,40})$", ErrorMessage = "Error en el formato de la contraseña.")]
```

And of course I can't use StringLength, for then it will never accept the field left empty:

```
[StringLength(40, ErrorMessage = "Password between 3 and 40 characters", MinimumLength = 3)]
```

What is the simplest way to solve this? Is a CustomValidator my only option?

Comment: Your post title is somewhat confusing... How can a password be "long" if it's empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing parentheses around your regular expression.
It should look like this:

```
^(()|([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,40}))$
```

The way you wrote it it will match `^()` or `([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,40}))$` which is any password - because any string begins with an empty one.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do the job:

```
public class OptionalPassword : ValidationAttribute
{
    private static Regex passwordPattern = 
        new Regex(@"^()|([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,40})$", 
                  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);

    public override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
    {
        var password = value as string;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password)) {
            return true;
        }

        return passwordPattern.IsMatch(password);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
    [OptionalPassword]
    public string Password { get; set; }
```

Comment: thanks for your input; it is not very different from the custom validator I'm trying to write, in case no better alternative is found.
there are some errors in that code though: for once, IsValid should return a ValidationResult.

Comment: I'll correct myself: IsValid returns a ValidationResult iff its signature includes the context parameter. public override bool IsValid(object value) is ok.

Comment: Thanks, now changed my answer - that'll teach me for not testing :)